# using two aggregate functions by using pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

At first, i have table structure with query:

```
>  SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, sales_timestamp) as MonthName, COUNT(*) as 
>          new_card_qty, ISNULL(sum(nc_deposit),0) as 
>          new_card_total,terminal_name
>          FROM dbfastshosted.dbo.fh_mf_new_card_logs cl
>          INNER JOIN dbfastshosted.dbo.fh_sales_map m on cl.nc_log_id = 
>          m.nc_log_id
>          INNER JOIN dbfastshosted.dbo.fh_sales_logs sl on m.sales_id = 
>          sl.sales_id 
>          INNER JOIN dbfastsconfigdataref.dbo.cdf_terminal_user_account h on 
>          cl.created_user_id = h.terminal_user_id
>          INNER JOIN dbfastsconfigdataref.dbo.cdf_terminal t on h.terminal_id = 
>          t.terminal_id
>          INNER JOIN dbfastsconfigdataref.dbo.cdf_cuid c on cl.cu_id = c.cu_id
>          where YEAR(sales_timestamp)='2017' 
>          and cl.currency_id = 2
>          and c.card_type_id = '514'
>          GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH, sales_timestamp), DATEPART(MONTH, 
>          sales_timestamp), terminal_name
>          ORDER BY DATEPART(MONTH, sales_timestamp), terminal_name

          MonthName new_card_qty    new_card_total    terminal_name

           January         7               40          Terminal 1
           February        6              55.00        Terminal 2
            March          1              10.00        Terminal 3
            ……..
            ………
            December        7            ....
```

And I wanted to have a structure table like this by using Pivot and managed to get the structure with the query:

```
  SELECT   terminal_name,  
     COUNT(JanuaryPcs) AS JanPcs,SUM(JanuaryAmt) AS JanAmt
    ,COUNT(FebruaryPcs) AS FebPcs,SUM(FebruaryAmt) AS FebAmt
    ,COUNT(MarchPcs) AS MarPcs,SUM(MarchAmt) AS MarAmt
    ,COUNT(AprilPcs) AS AprilPcs,SUM(AprilAmt) AS AprilAmt
    ,COUNT(MayPcs) AS MayPcs,SUM(MayAmt) AS MayAmt
    ,COUNT(JunePcs) AS JunePcs,SUM(JuneAmt) AS JuneAmt
    ,COUNT(JulyPcs) AS JulyPcs,SUM(JulyAmt) AS JulyAmt
    ,COUNT(AugustPcs) AS AugPcs,SUM(AugustAmt) AS AugAmt
    ,COUNT(SeptemberPcs) AS SepPcs,SUM(SeptemberAmt) AS SepAmt
    ,COUNT(OctoberPcs) AS OctPcs,SUM(OctoberAmt) AS OctAmt
    ,COUNT(NovemberPcs) AS NovPcs,SUM(NovemberAmt) AS NovAmt
    ,COUNT(DecemberPcs) AS DecPcs,SUM(DecemberAmt) AS DecAmt
   FROM (SELECT terminal_name,
         DATENAME(month,sales_timestamp)+'Pcs' AS MonthPcs,
         DATENAME(month,sales_timestamp)+'Amt' AS MonthAmt,
          ISNULL(sum(nc_deposit),0) AS AMOUNT,
         ISNULL(COUNT(nc_deposit),0) AS PIECES
   FROM dbfastshosted.dbo.fh_mf_new_card_logs cl
   INNER JOIN dbfastshosted.dbo.fh_sales_map m on cl.nc_log_id = m.nc_log_id
   INNER JOIN dbfastshosted.dbo.fh_sales_logs sl on m.sales_id = sl.sales_id 
   INNER JOIN dbfastsconfigdataref.dbo.cdf_terminal_user_account h on   
   cl.created_user_id = h.terminal_user_id
   INNER JOIN dbfastsconfigdataref.dbo.cdf_terminal t on h.terminal_id = 
   t.terminal_id
   INNER JOIN dbfastsconfigdataref.dbo.cdf_cuid c on cl.cu_id = c.cu_id
   WHERE YEAR(sales_timestamp)='2017' 
   and cl.currency_id = 2
   GROUP BY terminal_name,DATENAME(month,sales_timestamp)+'Pcs' AS MonthPcs,
   DATENAME(month,sales_timestamp)+'Amt') AS monthlysales
   PIVOT
    (COUNT(PIECES) FOR MonthPcs IN (JanuaryPcs,FebruaryPcs,
   MarchPcs,AprilPcs,MayPcs,JunePcs,JulyPcs,AugustPcs,SeptemberPcs, 
   OctoberPcs,NovemberPcs,DecemberPcs)) AS P1
   PIVOT
  (SUM(AMOUNT)FOR MonthAmt IN (JanuaryAmt,FebruaryAmt,MarchAmt,AprilAmt,
   MayAmt,JuneAmt,JulyAmt,AugustAmt, SeptemberAmt,OctoberAmt,
  NovemberAmt,DecemberAmt)) AS P2
  GROUP BY terminal_name;



  terminal_name JanPcs  JanAmt  FebPcs  FebAmt  MarPcs  MarAmt.. DecAmt
        terminal 1        1     10.00    1      20.00     1       30.0
```

But, the problem is the **count function doesn't work as the output is wrong** and keep display the same value for each month. 
Meanwhile the **Sum function works successfully**.I tried many times but it doesnt work. Is there any solution?

New updated code:

```
WITH source_table(terminal_name, Month_Name, piece, amount) AS
(
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, sales_timestamp) as Month_Name, COUNT(nc_deposit) as 
          piece, ISNULL(sum(nc_deposit),0) as 
         amount,terminal_name
          FROM dbfastshosted.dbo.fh_mf_new_card_logs cl
          INNER JOIN dbfastshosted.dbo.fh_sales_map m on cl.nc_log_id = 
          m.nc_log_id
         INNER JOIN dbfastshosted.dbo.fh_sales_logs sl on m.sales_id = 
          sl.sales_id 
          INNER JOIN dbfastsconfigdataref.dbo.cdf_terminal_user_account h on 
          cl.created_user_id = h.terminal_user_id
          INNER JOIN dbfastsconfigdataref.dbo.cdf_terminal t on h.terminal_id = 
         t.terminal_id
          INNER JOIN dbfastsconfigdataref.dbo.cdf_cuid c on cl.cu_id = c.cu_id
        where YEAR(sales_timestamp)='2017' 
          and cl.currency_id = 1
          and c.card_type_id = '514'
         GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH, sales_timestamp), MONTH(sales_timestamp),terminal_name
         ORDER BY MONTH(sales_timestamp), terminal_name             
)
Select   
    pieces.terminal_name, 
    pieces.January AS JanPcs,
    amounts.January AS JanAmt,
    pieces.February AS FebPcs,
    amounts.February AS FebAmt,
    pieces.March AS MarPcs,
    amounts.March AS MarAmt,
    pieces.April AS AprilPcs,
    amounts.April AS AprilAmt,
    pieces.May AS MayPcs,
    amounts.May AS MayAmt,
    pieces.June AS JunePcs,
    amounts.June AS JuneAmt,
    pieces.July AS JulyPcs,
    amounts.July AS JulyAmt,
    pieces.August AS AugustPcs,
    amounts.August AS AugustAmt,
    pieces.September AS SeptPcs,
    amounts.September AS SeptAmt,
    pieces.October AS OctPcs,
    amounts.October AS OctAmt,
    pieces.November AS NovPcs,
    amounts.November AS NovAmt, 
    pieces.December AS DecPcs,
    amounts.December AS DecAmt
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            (
              SELECT
                    terminal_name
                    ,Month_Name
                    ,piece
                FROM
                    source_table

            ) AS src_pieces
        PIVOT
            (
                MAX(piece)
                FOR Month_Name IN (January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December)
            ) AS pvt_pieces

    ) AS pieces

INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT
            *

        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    terminal_name
                    ,Month_Name
                    ,amount
                FROM
                    source_table

            ) AS src_pieces
        PIVOT
            (
                MAX(amount)
                FOR Month_Name IN (January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December)
            ) AS pvt_pieces
    ) AS amounts
 ON (amounts.terminal_name = pieces.terminal_name)
```

Comment: Hi @nur wahidah ur are using count function 2 times for pieces column(1 in select query and 1 in pivot) for that reason its not coming

Comment: For multiple aggregations for SQL pivot query, you can create two seperate pivot queries and UNION them. Please refer to http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/two-aggregate-functions-in-sql-server-pivot-table-query.aspx for a sample case

Comment: @Ajay can you show me the examples on how to do it?

Comment: @nurwahidah in the pivot use max() instead of count() as you are already using count function in the select query, (for exp in the 1 count() if the output is 10 the if u again taking count of the same value it will return count as 1)

Comment: @Ajay  i tried the solution but its not working

Comment: @nurwahidah in the sub query for pieces column u have taken ISNULL(sum(nc_deposit),0) AS AMOUNT,         ISNULL(COUNT(nc_deposit),0) AS PIECES both has same colmn name change the PIECES  column then u will get it.

Comment: @ajay both amount and pieces need to be retrieved by that specific column(nc_deposit). May I know what do you mean by change the PIECES column?

Comment: @nurwahidah in your query `nc_deposit` column holds which data?? Since you used same column for `count` and `sum` making confusion.

Comment: @ShakeerMirza count(nc_deposit) is to get the quantity of cards while sum(nc_deposit) is to get the sum of total sales of cards.

Answer (score 0):

The `COUNT(pieces)` in the pivot is counting the number of non-null values that will be rolled up into that particular cell - you are getting a value of 1 for all columns, because that is how many non-null values are being rolled up from the base query into the pivoted field.

The way I'd suggest you approach this problem is to first write a query (preferably using a WITH clause) that correctly produces a table (in standard, unpivoted form) with the following columns: `terminal_name`, `month_name`, `pieces`, `amount`.

When I say standard form, I mean that each terminal should have twelve rows associated with it (one for each month), and the pieces and amounts columns should be the relevant aggregate values for that terminal and that month. The logic of your code is a bit unclear, so I won't attempt to do it for you.

Once you have that sorted, you do two separate pivots, using only the MAX aggregate (since the SUMs and COUNTs have already been pre-done in the source table which is being pivoted - we use MAX just to select the single non-null value from the source table, since it contains only one value for each combination of terminal and month).

One pivot then produces the amounts columns, the other produces the count columns, and you interleave them in the select statement, in the same fashion as you have already done.

I've put together a working example below. I don't know whether I could have been a bit more economical with the syntax as I haven't ever needed to do a double pivot before, but I've followed a pattern that I know works correctly.

```
WITH source_table(terminal_name, month_name, pieces, amount) AS
(
    --PUT YOUR YOUR QUERY HERE INSTEAD OF THESE DUMMY VALUES
    SELECT 'Term1', 'Jan', 1, 10.00
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Term1', 'Feb', 5, 20.00
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Term1', 'Mar', 6, 30.00
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Term2', 'Jan', 7, 40.00
)

SELECT
    pieces.terminal_name

    ,pieces.Jan AS JanPcs
    ,amounts.Jan AS JanAmt

    ,pieces.Feb AS FebPcs
    ,amounts.Feb AS FebAmt

    ,pieces.Mar AS MarPcs
    ,amounts.Mar AS MarAmt

FROM
    (
        SELECT
            *

        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    terminal_name
                    ,month_name
                    ,pieces
                FROM
                    source_table

            ) AS src_pieces
        PIVOT
            (
                MAX(pieces)
                FOR month_name IN (Jan, Feb, Mar)
            ) AS pvt_pieces

    ) AS pieces

INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT
            *

        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    terminal_name
                    ,month_name
                    ,amount
                FROM
                    source_table

            ) AS src_pieces
        PIVOT
            (
                MAX(amount)
                FOR month_name IN (Jan, Feb, Mar)
            ) AS pvt_pieces

    ) AS amounts
    ON (amounts.terminal_name = pieces.terminal_name)
```

That produces the following output from the dummy values:

```
terminal_name JanPcs      JanAmt   FebPcs      FebAmt   MarPcs      MarAmt
------------- ----------- -------- ----------- -------- ----------- --------
Term1         1           10.00    5           20.00    6           30.00
Term2         7           40.00    NULL        NULL     NULL        NULL
```

**EDIT:**

Based on comments below and the updated code posted.

I noted straight away that you still have the `ORDER BY` clause inside the with-block. The order-by clause should go after the very bottom of the query in this case (on the very last line of the whole thing, after the joins between the two pivot tables).

It took me a further 10 minutes of scrutinising to realise that you are selecting the columns in the wrong order in the with-block.

The terminal_name should be selected first, then the month, then the pieces, then the amount (to match the column names defined on the with-block).

Note the order and names given to the columns:
`WITH source_table(terminal_name, month_name, pieces, amount) AS ...`

As you currently have it, based on the order you are selecting columns in your query, you are selecting the count (an int type) into the month column, the month name into the terminal_name column, the amount into the pieces column, and the terminal_name into the amount column.

You will have your own particular style but you should try to get into the habit of formatting your SQL properly and as consistently as possible. Each column you select should be written on a separate line and intended from the `SELECT` keyword. (The exception in my original post with the dummy values union-ed together, and all columns selected on one row, was a special case and a compromise for clarity in that particular case!)

So rather than this:

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, sales_timestamp) as Month_Name, COUNT(nc_deposit) as 
      piece, ISNULL(sum(nc_deposit),0) as 
     amount,terminal_name
      FROM ...
```

It should look something like this (with the column order corrected as per the above):

```
SELECT
    terminal_name
    ,DATENAME(MONTH, sales_timestamp) AS Month_Name
    ,COUNT(nc_deposit)                AS piece
    ,ISNULL( SUM(nc_deposit), 0 )     AS amount

FROM ...
```

With SQL you will suffer endless pain from poor formatting.

Comment: thanks @steve.i have followed your example but iam getting this error :              Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 22
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: @nurwahidah, I can't see the explanation for that, as my example code does not contain an order-by clause, and I have tested it working. If you have included an order-by clause yourself, it should go at the very bottom of the query after the inner join - not inside the WITH block.

Comment: @steve..i have put the order-by clause after the inner join and  getting these two error
#Error converting data type nvarchar to int
#The incorrect value "January" is supplied in the PIVOT operator.

Comment: @nurwahidah, post your new code (add it to the bottom of your original post) and I can have a look at it.

Comment: @nurwahidah, I've updated my post with additional advice.

Comment: yes i put the order by at the bottom but thats giving me the error @steve

Comment: @nurwahidah, have you also corrected the order of the columns being selected in the with-block?

Comment: i cant even put the order- by as it give me error invalid column : sales_timestamp @steve

Comment: I'll have to leave it with you then to solve any problems in the source query. Like I said in my original answer, you should ensure the source query is fully working, before applying the pivoting logic (i.e. the parts I've written for you).